# Signed apk shows a black screen, while debug version shows just fine

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-debug, signed-apk

Working with debug build variant, my app works just fine. However, when I sign the app and install it, it starts with a black screen. This is what I have in build.gradle:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Weird thing is, if i set debuggable true in release, there's no black screen and the app works just fine again. But the problem is I cannot publish an app with debuggable flag set to true.

I'm completely stuck and could not find any similar issue. Any help would be really appreciated.

As I said, I cannot even debug with the release version, since the problem happens when debuggable is false.

Comment: you are using proguard, with proguard false it is working on release?

Comment: Just tried with minifyEnabled false and debuggable false, and it doesn't work either. So the problem is setting debuggable as false, apparently...I really don't get it. Any hint?

Comment: what need to be displayed on the screen? what kind of widgets? maybe map or other third api's?

Comment: It's an Activity with a DrawerLayout and NavigationView, which has inside a RecyclerView. Each RecyclerView item loads a different Fragment. There's really nothing weird inside the Fragment, maybe it has to do with any third party library I use? In this case, I use SmoothRefreslLayout https://github.com/dkzwm/SmoothRefreshLayout

Comment: what theme you are using?

Comment: ```<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/register_text</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/register_text</item>
    </style>```